# Tuning a cascaded attitude and attitude rate PID controller

Tags: control-theory, pid-control, robotics

Assume that I have an object in 3D, and I want to have a controller that stabilizes its orientation (also referred to as "attitude").

To be sure we are clear:

- attitude is measured in "degrees" or "radians"
- attitude rate is measured in "degrees/s" or "radians/s"

The controller is made of two cascaded control loops:

- attitude controller: the error controlled by this controller is the difference between the *reference attitude* and the *real attitude*
- attitude rate controller: the error controlled by this controller is the difference between the  reference *attitude rate* and the *real attitude rate*

The attitude controller is made only of a P term, and therefore it is not hard to tune. However, the attitude rate controller has all three terms P, I, and D.

I am using the well-known [Ziegler-Nichols method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method) to tune the attitude rate controller. However, I am not sure that theoretically, what I am doing is correct.

My question is: is it possible to tune the P, I, and D terms of the attitude rate controller while observing the step response by giving a command in attitude? To apply this procedure, should I provide an attitude rate command instead? (The main problem is I cannot give an attitude rate command because my object would start to rotate and this is not practical). FYI and for completeness: my object is a drone, but I don't think it matters too much regarding my question.

Comment: Do you have maybe a mathematical model of the system ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You touch a really important point: there is no nonlinear mathematical model in this case. The whole system is treated as a rigid body. The only thing you change when you change to a different drone is the mass of your drone.

Comment: Well, different drones, even the exact same models, come with manufacturing differences. The mathematical model is responsible to take care of these differences and of course it does not have to be nonlinear. Even a highly nonlinear model can be approached satisfactory by a linear model. I intended to tell you to perform a system identification before designing your controller but I don't know your background in control engineering-theory.

Comment: Of course, I understand what you mean and I completely agree with you. What I meant is that the model here is not important. I can't change the control architecture because it comes from an open-source firmware (PX4) that we are using. 

Model identification is another option but my question was different and it is a more general one. Is the procedure I explain correct?

You can consider my background in control engineering advanced, thanks again for your help and precious time.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if I understand correctly what the phrase "by giving a command in attitude" means but generally the procedure you are explaining is correct. Basically, you need to tune the PID directly on the "real system" without a model. From what I am aware of (and the bibliography) this is manageable by following certain steps, particularly in the Ziegler-Nichols method while observing the behaviour of the system during these steps. And yes, step commands (as attitude reference) is almost always a good way to start with.

Comment: So technically it goes like this: Send a reference input to the system, follow the tuning steps for the PID gains (tuning the P term comes first in Ziegler-Nichols method). Observe the output of the system with respect to the reference input (basically the error of the manipulated variable $e = y_{desired} - y_{measured}$) until you reach an acceptable level.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I know well how Ziegler-Nichols works. Now my doubt is the following. Can I do the following:
- give an "attitude" command (e.g., roll of 20 degrees, pitch of 20 degrees)
- observe the "attitude" response
- tune the "attitude rate" gains ? 

I ask because usually you would do: 
- give an "attitude" command (e.g., roll of 20 degrees, pitch of 20 degrees)
- observe the "attitude" response
- tune the "attitude" gains

Comment: I am not quite sure if you can tune a controller with respect to some other reference. I, personally would not do it. But consider maybe this: giving a constant reference (let's say 20 degrees roll), the derivative will be always 0 which (if I have understood correctly the control system) is the reference point of the controller for the "attitude rate". I suppose you always want 0 "attitude rate" when reaching your desired attitude. So, maybe this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your system is a drone, it is very hard to control the whole attitude at once. Instead, what is standard is controlling each of the three Euler angles, corresponding to rotation in each direction (i.e $\phi,\theta,\psi$). Additionally, the dynamics are nonlinear, although you can linearize them which is also standard procedure.

So what you should do if you actually want to implement this: look up the dynamics for your system (what are your state variables, what are your control inputs). Then try to do PID controller for pitch and see how that works. You can do the same for roll and yaw, but sometimes what people do is since roll and yaw are highly coupled, they implement a coupled controller for both instead of two separate ones. In any case, you have many choices here but you need a solid model first for analysis.